# Passing variable length struct from User Mode to Kernel Mode

Tags: c, windows, drivers, wdk

I'm writing virtual disk driver, and there I have structure defined like that:

```
typedef struct _MOUNT_NEW_QUERY {
    PWCHAR imagePath;
    WCHAR letter;
    PCHAR key;
} MOUNT_NEW_QUERY, *PMOUNT_NEW_QUERY;
```

So I have sort of dynamically sized structure.

How must I pass it from User Mode to my driver?

Comment: Think `"foo\0bar\0\baz\0"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allocate a continuous chunk of memory, sufficient to hold both your struct and the data for "key" and "path" - something like this:

```
/* we add + 1 for terminating NULLs to make life easy */
size_t keyLen = (strlen(key) +  1); 
size_t imgLen = (wcslen(imagePath) + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR);

PMOUNT_NEW_QUERY pMNQ = malloc(sizeof(MOUNT_NEW_QUERY) + keyLen + imgLen);

if(pMNQ != NULL) 
{       
   /* make imagePath point to the allocated buffer immediately after 
    * the MOUNT_NEW_QUERY portion 
    */
   pMNQ->imagePath = (PWCHAR)((PBYTE)pMNQ + sizeof(MOUNT_NEW_QUERY));

   /* make the key point to the allocated buffer immediately after 
    * the imagePath portion (including a NULL WCHAR terminator)
    */
   pMNQ->key = (PCHAR)((PBYTE)pMNQ + sizeof(MOUNT_NEW_QUERY) + imgLen);

   /* populate the data here appropriately, typically with strcpy
    * and wcscpy, and then send the IOCTL 
    */
   fun(pMNQ);
}
```

When you call the IOCTL for your driver, pass the *total* size of the buffer, not just the sizeof the MOUNT_NEW_QUERY structure.

Comment: Oh it's easy... I think I understand. Thank you.  
Sorry can't vote up, don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Hmm... And one more question. Should I add length of array to struct?
**UPD:** Sorry again. It seems I need more sleep. =)